# Plotly: How to remove leading 0s from tick labels

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a [plotly](https://plot.ly/) plot with 'time of day' on the x axis (e.g. 5:00 AM), but some of the labels include leading 0s (e.g. 05:00 AM). I would like to remove these leading 0s but am not sure how.

Example:

```
library(plotly)

# Data
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "America/Chicago")
end <- as.POSIXct("2018-01-02 00:00:00", tz = "America/Chicago")
times <- seq.POSIXt(start, end, by = "60 mins")
df <- data.frame(x = times, y = seq_along(times))

# Plot
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df,
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",  # "lines",
    line = list(shape = "linear", dash = "dot", width = 3),
    marker = list(size = 12)
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Foo",
    xaxis = list(title = NA, showgrid = TRUE, autotick = F, dtick = 1000*60*60*2, tickformat = "%I:%M %p")
  )
```

[image]

How can I get rid of those pesky leading 0s?

Comment: do you mean `tickformat = "%H %p"`?

Comment: @MLavoie no. That format still has leading 0s and it incorrectly displays "2PM" as "14PM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tickformat = "%-I:%M %p"` (for more details see [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format))

```
# Plot
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df,
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines+markers",  # "lines",
    line = list(shape = "linear", dash = "dot", width = 3),
    marker = list(size = 12)
  ) %>%
  layout(
    title = "Foo",
    xaxis = list(title = NA, showgrid = TRUE, autotick = F, dtick = 1000*60*60*2, tickformat = "%-I:%M %p")
  )
```

[image]